# using multiple comparators in a java binarySearch

Tags: java

How do I use multiple comparators in a binarySearch in java...
I'm trying to sort a list of contestants which are sorted by name and their starting number.

The problem is if two contestants have the same name I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException so I want to do a secondary binarySearch using the starting number (which is unique) but still keeping them in the right order with names.

This is what I've got right now:

```
static void add(Contestant c){
    int pos = Collections.binarySearch(byName, c, new ConNameCmp());
    if (pos >= 0){
        pos = Collections.binarySearch(byName, c, new ConStartCmp());
    }
    byName.add(-pos-1, c);
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for your avoiding of `TreeSet`?

Answer (score 5):

### One Comparator only

Don't use two Comparators, use a single Comparator that compares both values:

```
public int compare(Foo a, Foo b){
    // compare bar() values first
    int result = a.bar().compareTo(b.bar());
    // compare baz() values only if bar() values are different
    if(result==0){
        result = a.baz().compareTo(b.baz());
    }
    return result;
}
```

(In your case bar() is the name and baz() is the number).

### Use Libraries

Creating Comparators this way is a lot easier if you use either [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or [Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

**Guava Versions:**

```
@Override
public int compare(final Foo a, final Foo b){
    return ComparisonChain
        .start()
        .compare(a.bar(), b.bar())
        .compare(a.baz(), b.baz())
        .result();
}
```

**Commons / Lang Version:**

```
@Override
public int compare(final Foo a, final Foo b){
    return new CompareToBuilder()
        .append(a.bar(), b.bar())
        .append(a.baz(), b.baz())
        .toComparison();
}
```

(Both of these versions won't fail if any of the values are null, my quick and dirty code above will)

### Solve the Problem

I don't think you should do a Binary search in the first place, this seems very complicated.

Why don't you use a [`TreeSet` with a custom comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29)? Or [`Collections.sort(list, comparator)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%2C%20java.util.Comparator%29)? (For both of these options you can use the comparators I showed earlier).

Also, you should think about letting your Contestant implement `Comparable<Contestant>`. That way you won't need to use an external `Comparator`. You can use the same logic as above in the `compareTo()` method, just replace one of the objects with `this`.

Comment: Note, the Collections.sort() call is already required in order for the binary search to work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already tried this, and this solution might not be available to you, but if you can change your "`Contestant`" class, you can make it extend the "`java.lang.Comparable`" interface and override `Comparable#compareTo(Contestant)` method so that it takes both the name and starting number into account. Afterwards, you'll be able to use the `Collections.binarySearch(Collection<Contestant>, Contestant)` method for your need.